# How to fix Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add() on string

Tags: php, date, fpdf

Am trying to print the date to pdf using fpdf library, but there is an error.

```php
$date = date("F j, Y");
$date->add(new DateInterval('P14D'));
$this->Cell(185, 5, 'Due Date: '.date_format($date, 'Y-m-d'), 0, 0, 'R');
```

I need to add 14 days to the current date and print

Comment: `date` as you call it returns a string, not an object. `date("F j, Y", strtotime('+14 days'));` might be what you want

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing procedural `date()` functions and DateTime objects. If you want to use DateTime objects, then do

```php
$date = new DateTime;
$date->add(new DateInterval('P14D'));
$this->Cell(185, 5, 'Due Date: '.($date->format('Y-m-d')), 0, 0, 'R');
```

You can also use the `+14 days` string and just create the object 14 days ahead of today,

```php
$date = new DateTime("+14 days");
$this->Cell(185, 5, 'Due Date: '.($date->format('Y-m-d')), 0, 0, 'R');
```

Or if you want to stick with procedural `date()`,

```php
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+14 days"));
$this->Cell(185, 5, 'Due Date: '.$date, 0, 0, 'R');
```

Comment: I tried all of your suggestions and they worked, but I went with the second one. Thanks

Comment: Good call, I would have chosen the same. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
$date =  new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P14D'));
```

In order to use the `DateInterval` you need to use the `DateTime` class. Use above code.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Removed it since the OP is formatting anyway in the next step. The issue was in the add function anyways. Thanks for pointing!!!